# ImportError: libOpenNI.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, openni, nite

I am trying to get PyOpenNi working on an Odroid U3 with lubuntu 14.04.1.

I have installed openni 1.5.2, nite 1.5.2, and primesense drivers for use with Asus Xtion Pro Live.

After installing PyOpenNi and trying to import via python I receive the following error.

```
ImportError: libOpenNI.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have made sure that libOpenNI.so is in /usr/lib/, that the path is in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable, and run sudo ldconfig.

There is not a lot out there on the web, and the PyOpenNI guys couldn't really help me with this one and suggested I ask it here.

Thanks in advance for the help!